# Can I use the Ubuntu font in a proprietary application?

Tags: proprietary, ubuntu-font-family, license

Huge Ubuntu fan here, I really like the Ubuntu font, but as far as I know you may only use it in open-source applications. I want to use it in an iPhone/iPad app. Due to Apple's contracts, I can't make the project open-source.

So, the question actually is, is it allowed to use/distribute the Ubuntu font in an iPhone/iPad application (free or paid)? Would be great if that's allowed!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not forced to use the font with free/open source applications. The license just states that you must distribute the license together with the font itself. The license also says what you have to do when you modify the font, but this is not your case.

It is very short and you can read it here: http://font.ubuntu.com/ufl/

If you are seeking a more authoritative answer, remember that Canonical is always available to help you: legal AT canonical.com

Comment: So, adding the license to the software in an about-screen or so would be enough? :-)

Comment: @Robbietjuh Yes, adding it in the about screen would work. Also, keep in mind that iOS might not let you use a custom font like that, back when I was reading the docs (~2 years ago) there was no way to do it. However, that might have changed since then.

Comment: Thanks guys. @jrg It's possible now with iOS 5. Now we can create beautiful apps with the Ubuntu font :D You might want to start reading some documentation again :-) Never too late to learn.